# Word frequency analysis in Python returning letter frequency

Tags: python

Following examples on other Stackoverflow posts related to word frequency analysis in Python, my program is returning letter frequency analysis and not actually the word.

I'm currently reading in my corpa from a text file as shown below in my code.

```
from collections import Counter
def word_frequency_counter():
    contents = ""

    with open("file.txt") as f:
            contents += str(f.readlines())

    commonWords = Counter(contents)#= Counter(str(contents.lower())).most_common()

    print "The top three words are: ", str(commonWords.most_common(3))
```

The output is this:

```
The top three words are:  [(' ', 1126), ("'", 538), ('n', 528)]
```

My desired output would be actual words, while also having a set of ignored words such as white space characters and quotations.

Comment: You probably want `Counter(f.read().split())` rather than `Counter(str(f.readlines()).split())`, `readlines` returns an array with length equal to the number of lines in the file while `read` returns the entire file as a string, including the newline characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Counter(contents.split())
```

should use words instead ...

Answer (score 0):

`contents` is a string, and strings in Python are iterable (i.e. strings behave like lists of letters in this context) so your Counter is counting letters.

You need to pass the Counter a list of words, not a string of letters.

Joran's answer shows how to do this using `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to find all the word (vs character by character that you are getting now):

```
import re

...

commonWords = Counter(m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'\b(\w+)\b', contents))
```

You can use `contents.split()` to split the text on whitespace but that will not separate words from punctuation. You will also have a separate count for `word` and `word,` and `word.` etc which using a regex will fix.